# Convert date with moment one character

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

How to convert data with moment JS, I'm using: 
moment(time, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); - and it returns ex. 15 days ago.
I need to format that to 15 d ago. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customise this via the [locale settings for relative time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/).

Just do something like the following:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "s",
        m:  "1 min",
        mm: "%d min",
        h:  "1 h",
        hh: "%d h",
        d:  "1 d",
        dd: "%d d",
        M:  "1 mth",
        MM: "%d mth",
        y:  "1 y",
        yy: "%d y"
    }
});
```

Now `moment("20150623", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()` will return `6 d ago`.

Comment: TypeError: moment.locale is not a function - when using moment.locale

Comment: @EdonBajrami What version of MomentJS are you using? According to [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) which I linked, `moment.locale()` is used in version 2.8.1 onwards, whilst prior to that you use `moment.lang()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the function returns a string "15 days ago".

Under this assumption, you could save it as a string and then use substrings and regular expressions to parse it to the desired format. If it is always going to be of the form "X days ago" though, you could just grab up to the first space, and then add " d ago" to the end of it, in a new string.